# Exclude div from css table properties

Tags: css, css-tables

i have a CSS-table like this: http://jsfiddle.net/JZAr8/

```
<div style="display:table;width:100%">
<div style="display:table-row;">
<div style="display:table-cell;border:1px solid grey;">table-cell</div>
<div style="display:table-cell;border:1px solid grey;">table-cell</div>
</div><!-- row -->
<div style="border:1px solid grey;width:100%">testdiv</div>
<div style="display:table-row;">
<div style="display:table-cell;border:1px solid grey;">table-cell</div>
<div style="display:table-cell;border:1px solid grey;">table-cell</div>
</div><!-- row -->
</div><!-- table -->​
```

it seems like 'testdiv' is still connected to the table properties and is interpreted as a table-cell ... Why is this the case? How can I "exclude" the testdiv from the table...?

Comment: I think it will be better to create tables using the `table` tag, after all, that's what they are for.

Comment: It's essentially the same as putting a `<div>` inside of a `<table>`. That's not allowed and the resulting behavior is **undefined**.

Comment: +1 to animuson. The browser seems to add what he thinks is missing, like a `table-row` element as a parent to your testdiv. Table algorithms will correct many "errors" like missing or extra cells.

Comment: Dear see my answer and let me know if i am lagging some where.

Comment: see my comment on my answer for some clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You just remove this div:

```
<div style="border:1px solid grey;width:100%">testdiv</div>
```

and it goes away:

[As it is here](http://jsfiddle.net/JZAr8/1/)

Answer (score 0):

See the fiddle for demo.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JZAr8/2/

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JZAr8/2/embedded/result/

Note: To overcome from the textdiv, i just move the testdiv from the table divs. It is up to you whther you want to keep the testdiv or delete it.

Comment: This is not the result i was looking for. I thought that i will see the cells, than the testdiv in the middle. But the testdiv has a kind of cell-behaviour but it is not set up as table-cell; ... my impression now is, that the browser correct this automatically and thinks that it must be a cell because it is in the middle of a table. Damn.

Comment: if you set display: table-row; on test div then issues will solve but you requirement it browser should show like this. I think it is not possible. because this the behavior of table, if not specified the td it will not create the cell for example see the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qZHEC/1/